# What is the best use of Inheritance other than reduce redundant code?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, coding-style, instance

What is the best use of Inheritance, other than it will reduce redundant code!
Let us take an example
Class A:Base Class
Class B:Sub Class
and Class C.

```
 CLASS A
    ^
    |                And     CLASS C
    |
    |
  CLASS B
```

i can use methods from Class A, in Class B by inheritance.
in the same i can use the methods from Class A, in Class C, 
by creating instance of Class A.(say A is Public)
using inheritance, only reduce creating new Object/Instance?
 
Plz help me to better understand!

Comment: Get yourself a copy of "Head First: Design Patterns" (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do) and spend some time finding answers on what are the common use cases for inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great benefit is polymorphism. If classes B and C both inherit from A, then whenever an object of type A is required, it can be replaced by either an object of type B or an object of type C. Assuming the corresponding methods are overriden in B and C, this is very handy to get different behavior depending on which object you pass.

Example:

```
class A {
    public void foo() { System.out.println("A"); }
}

class B extends A {
    public void foo() { System.out.println("B"); }
}

class C extends A {
    public void foo() { System.out.println("C"); }
}
```

Then:

```
public static void printMessage(A obj) {
    obj.foo();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    A b = new B();
    printMessage(b); // prints 'B'
    A c = new C();
    printMessage(c); // prints 'C'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main point of inheritance is polymorphism: to allow *other* classes to use an instance of `ClassB` knowing only that it can be used as a `ClassA`.

My favourite example is streams - I could easily write a `copyStream` method taking an `InputStream` and an `OutputStream` for example, using only the methods declared on those types. Then I could copy a `FileInputStream` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, or use network-related streams etc, all without changing any of the code in the `copyStream` method.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to use inheritance is not to remove redundant code.

Inheritance and all magic made possible is a key, central point in OOP. Extending a class doesn't only allow you to use its functionality, but also modify (by polimorphism) and add more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The difference comes with the need to understand the ability to pass class B into functions that act on class A. In this sense B is-a type of A where class C has or owns A. The difference is small and only significant in certain circumstance.

That is not to say that the difference is often made explicit in code tbh. Often people will inherit when they really want ownership and sometimes they do ownership when an object really is-a type of something else.